# show that for any x,y element of X, |D(x,B)-D(y,B)| < d(x,y)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The distance D(x, B) from a point x to a non-empty subset B of (X, d)
is defined to be D(x, B)= inf d(x, b), where b is an element of B.
So I must show that for any x,y is an element of X that 
|D(x,B)-D(y,B)| <= d(x,y).
I started this question by using the definition of the infimum and stating that |D(x,B)-D(y,B)| <= d(x,y)<=|D(x,B)-D(y,B)| +1/n and would like to know if I am on the right track or not and if I am not then could someone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x,y \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $b\in B$ such that $d(y,b) < D(y,B) + \epsilon$. Then $$D(x,B) \le d(x,b) \le d(x,y) + d(y,b) \le d(x,y) + D(y,B) + \epsilon$$ which implies $$D(x,B) - D(y,B) \le d(x,y) + \epsilon.$$ By a similar argument, $$D(y,B) - D(x,B) \le d(x,y) + \epsilon.$$ Therefore $$|D(x,B) - D(y,B)| \le d(x,y) + \epsilon.$$ Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $|D(x,B) - D(y,B)| \le d(x,y)$.

Comment: where does the fact that D(x, B)= inf d(x, b)  come into play here?

Comment: Since $d(y,B) = \inf\{d(y,b):b\in B\}$, for a given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $b\in B$ such that $d(y,b) < d(y,B) + \epsilon$.

Comment: does it matter that in the question it actually states that d(x,B)= ..... instead of d(y,B)?

Comment: They defined it for all $x\in X$, not just a particular $x$.